# ¿Por qué no carga la imagen de la URL especificada?

Tags: html, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <Title>Hiperenlaces</Title>

 </head>

 <body>

  <a href="https://www.google.es/" target="_blank">Enlace a Google en otra pestaña</a> <br/>
  <a href="https://www.google.es/" target="_self">Enlace a Google en esta pestaña</a> <br/>
  <a href="imagenes/html.jpg">Enlace a un archivo dentro del servidor</a> 

 </body>

</html>
```

En la línea donde especifico la URL de la imagen `<a href="imagenes/html.jpg">` no me carga el archivo de imagen que está alojado en el servidor.

¿Cómo hago para que cargue el archivo de imagen al hacer clic en el enlace?

Comment: y la ruta que declaras si estqa correcta? podrías anexar a tu pregunta estructura de carpoetas que tines?

Comment: a si mismo te pregunto los nombres de carpeta y archivo estan correctos?

Comment: Si, son correctos

Comment: entonces muestranos por favor la información que te comento

Comment: La carpeta es curso html donde esta el codigo y hay una subcarpeta llamada imagenes donde esta html.jpg

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos puedes probar indicando con ./  que acceda a la carpeta imágenes que esta al mismo nivel del archivo **HTML** que estas mostrando en tu pregunta:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="./imagenes/sociedad.jpg">Hola</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Del modo anterior asumo que tu orden de archivos es así:

```
-proyecto_web
   -imagenes
       sociedad.png
   index.html
```

Entonces con el ./imagenes/sociedad.png le pides busque en la carpeta imagenes que esta al mismo nivel del HTML

Lo anterior con respecto a las respuestas que me diste en los comentarios

Comment: Muchas gracias! me has ayudado un monton. No es un proyecto, es un curso que he iniciado de html y necesitaba ayuda, y tu me has ayudado. Vuelvo a acerte la pelota, GRACIAS

Comment: de nada saludos

Answer (score 0):

Sin conocer exactamente la estructura de tu solución me da que el problema puede ser que falte una barra antes de la carpeta "imagenes":

href="/imagenes/..."

Si el HTML está en tu raíz necesitas esa barra, si está dentro de una carpeta entonces sería como has puesto.

Más info: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp